# confirmation box in php?

Tags: javascript, php

My PHP script has a link to external API. I want it to be in such a way that when I run the script  a confirmation box should appear and it should ask "are you sure, you want to continue?", with two buttons: 'yes' and 'no'. When I click yes, I want to continue the process and when I click no, nothing should happen and the page will close.

My code:

```
$curl = curl.init();

curl_opt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL =>1,
CURL_URL ==> "http://10.10.10.10/list/list17?ip=192.1.1.1", ))

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
$info =curl_getinfo($curl);
$ststusCode = $info["http_code"];

curl_close($curl);

if($statusCode ==200) {
echo '<h1>good</h1>
}else{
echo '<h1> Error</h1>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Create one more php file like ```process.php```. Keep  2 links ```YES``` & ```NO```  in that file. On click of ```YES``` link call your Script & on click of ```NO``` do something else.

Comment: Can you show some example ? 10x

Comment: Suppose your script name is ```api.php```. So, what I'm telling create one more PHP file like ```process.php```having 2 anchor link. ```<a href='api.php'>YES</a> & <a href='somethingelse.php'>NO</a>```. That's it!!!. When user click on YES it'll take him to ```api.php``` & execute those codes.

Comment: It's not good for me. I have to do it in one file.

Comment: In one file by using PHP it's not possible. Because PHP executes on the server side & since if you use one file.. when PHP start to execute the codes from top to bottom no way u can make any arrangements to give a PAUSE to the execution of code & take instruction from the user.

Comment: Can I do it with javascript as part of the file?

Comment: By use Javascript, u can do but, not everything in a single file. In case of Javascript it'll be like... create one HTML file like ```index.html```. when html will load on the browser it'll generate one Confirmation box & ask u for ```yes/no```. If u click ```YES``` it'll make a AJAX call to your ```api.php```.

Answer (score 0):

The same solution as mi6crazyheart but in one file:

```
if( isset($_GET['confirm']) && $_GET['confirm'] == "yes" )
{
    $curl = curl.init();

    curl_opt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL =>1,
    CURL_URL ==> "http://10.10.10.10/list/list17?ip=192.1.1.1", ))

    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $info =curl_getinfo($curl);
    $ststusCode = $info["http_code"];

    curl_close($curl);

    if($statusCode ==200) {
    echo '<h1>good</h1>';
    }else{
    echo '<h1> Error</h1>';
    }
}
?>

<a href="api.php?confirm=yes">YES</a> & <a href="api.php?confirm=no">NO</a>
```